# How can I know how many users have joined through invite link of telegram group which I have created?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have created a link of telegram group using createChatInviteLInk using my bot present in that group now i want see how many users have joined through particular link programtically

Answer (score 0):

You should check invite_link in [ChatMemberUpdated](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated) object. You'll receive it as Update (field chat_member) when a user join from link.

Note: chat_member is not default in allowed_updates. You have to specify "chat_member" there

Comment: how should i call this can you please tell

Comment: I do not have invite_link in my_chat_member field of the update. Probably I miss something.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The field is in chat_member. my_chat_member is for updates of the bot itself. I fixed my answer